# CakePHP and linker tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following 3 tables in my CakePHP app:

```
**posts**
id
title
content

**tags**
id
title

**posts_tags**
id
post_id
tag_id
```

As you can see I have Posts which can have tags attached to them and this is stored in a linker table called posts_tags. The problem is I'm confused as to how to set this up in CakePHP?

As I have a Controller for Posts and Tags as well as Model. Although when creating tags with a post the logic is done in the Posts Controller. But how would I save to the linker table as well as Tags and Posts table properly? Is there a nice easy way to deal with the associations in this type of scenario?

I have the associations for Posts and Authors set up fine (user table not shown) as it's just a simple one to many relationship, but what about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this is using Cake's "hasMany through (The Join Model)"

See section of the Cakebook:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model

Then in your controller, use ->saveAll() to save the data:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array

Comment: Any chance you should show a quick example of how I might do this in a method?

Comment: The first link has an example with 3 tables and their respective models + associations.  Just substitute your tables. (i.e. CourseMembership is analogous to your PostsTags)